# JSON_QUERY to do a "Select Many"

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, json-query

I have a JSON variable that looks like this (the real one is more complex):

```
DECLARE @myJson VARCHAR(3000) = '{
    "CustomerId": "123456",
    "Orders": [{
            "OrderId": "852",
            "OrderManifests": [{
                    "ShippedProductId": 884,
                    "ProductId": 884
                }, {
                    "ShippedProductId": 951,
                    "ProductId": 2564
                }    
            ]
        }, {
            "OrderId": "5681",
            "OrderManifests": [{
                    "ShippedProductId": 198,
                    "ProductId": 4681
                }, {
                    "ShippedProductId": 8188,
                    "ProductId": 8188
                }, {
                    "ShippedProductId": 144,
                    "ProductId": 8487
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

In the end, I need to know if any of the *ShippedProductId* values match their corresponding *ProductId* (in the same JSON object).

I started in by trying to get a list of all the *OrderManifests*.  But while this will get me the array of orders:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@myJson, '$.Orders')
```

I can't seem to find a way to get a list of all the *OrderManifests* across all the entries in the *Orders* array.  This does not work:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(@myJson, '$.Orders.OrderManifests')
```

Is there a way to do a Select Many kind of query to get all the *OrderManifests* in the *Orders* array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OPENJSON` and `CROSS APPLY` to drill down into your objects.

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT j.CustomerId,o.OrderId, m.ShippedProductId, m.ProductId
FROM OPENJSON(@myJson)
WITH (
    CustomerId NVARCHAR(1000),
    Orders NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.Orders)
WITH (
    OrderId NVARCHAR(1000),
    OrderManifests NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) o
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(o.OrderManifests)
WITH (
    ShippedProductId INT,
    ProductId int
) m
WHERE m.ShippedProductId = m.ProductId;
```

This query returns:

```
CustomerId  |  OrderId  |  ShipedProductId  |  ProductId
------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------
123456      |    852    |       884         |     884
------------+-----------+-------------------+-------------
123456      |   5681    |      8188         |    8188
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not familiar with OPENJSON.  I will have to look into that more.  They query you gave me errors out on my machine, but I can dig into OPENJSON and see if it can do what I need.  (FYI, there are two errors it gives me:  *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.* on line 5 and *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.* on lines 8 and 13)

Comment: Interesting.  It works perfectly on my SQL 2019 instance with your sample JSON.  Are you sure you have the whole query highlighted when running it?  You also might need a semicolon somewhere above it if you are running it with other things.  `WITH` is not part of a CTE in this case.

Comment: Ah, my DB's compatibility level is too lower for OPENJSON.  I will see if I can get the Compatibility level raised.

Comment: Ah yes, that would do it.  Needs to be 130 or higher.